# Expand rows of dataframe via a another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with many rows and columns. One column specifies the path to a file that contains more data:

```
        name             path
1          a      /path/a.csv
2          b      /path/b.csv
```

I want to read that file, then expand my rows with the dataframe created from that file (i.e. `readr::read_csv`:

Example files `a.csv`

```
      t     x
1     1     3
2     2     1
3     3     6
```

and `b.csv`:

```
      t     x
1     1     4
2     2     3
3     3     5
4     4     1
```

*Desired output*

```
   name     t     x
1     a     1     3
2     a     2     1
3     a     3     6
4     b     1     4
5     b     2     3
6     b     3     5
7     b     4     1
```

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for problems specific to the code editor RStudio (e.g., you have code that work in the RGui or command line, but it doesn't work in RStudio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_data$df = lapply(your_data$path, read_csv)
tidyr::unnest(your_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using purrr::map_df

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  deframe %>%
  map_df(read_csv, .id = "name")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
   name     t     x
  <chr> <int> <int>
1     a     1     3
2     a     2     1
3     a     3     6
4     b     1     4
5     b     2     3
6     b     3     5
7     b     4     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your first data file is called `index`,

```
do.call(rbind,apply(index, 1, function(X){temp = read.csv(X[2]);cbind(name=X[1], temp)}))
```

Alternatively, a `for` loop should make the code cleaner:

```
combined = NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(index)){
  temp = read.csv(index$path[i])
  combined = rbind(combined, cbind(name = index$name[i], temp))
}
```